# How can I pass a created array from Custom adapter class to other class?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to pass a String list from my custom array class to another class, but for some reason when I try to access the list, it always seems empty.

Here is my Custom Adapter class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private final List<Model> orders;
    private final Context context;
    boolean checkAll_flag = false;
    boolean checkItem_flag = false;
    public List<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();


    public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<Model> orders) {

        super(context, R.layout.company_list_order, orders);
        this.context = context;
        this.orders = orders;

    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView orderText;
        protected CheckBox checkOrder;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.company_list_order, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.orderText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewList);
            viewHolder.checkOrder = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listCheckBox);

            viewHolder.checkOrder.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                    orders.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                    if (orders.get(getPosition).isSelected()) {
                        selectedItems.add(orders.get(getPosition).getName());
                        Log.d("Add", "Item added: " + orders.get(getPosition).getName());
                        Log.d("Size", "Selected items " + selectedItems.size());
                    } else {
                        selectedItems.remove(orders.get(getPosition).getName());
                        Log.d("Remove", "Item removed: " + orders.get(getPosition).getName());
                        Log.d("Size", "Selected items " + selectedItems.size());
                    }
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.textViewList, viewHolder.orderText);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.listCheckBox, viewHolder.checkOrder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.checkOrder.setTag(position);

        viewHolder.orderText.setText(orders.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.checkOrder.setChecked(orders.get(position).isSelected());

        return convertView;

    }

    public List<String> getListItems() {
        return selectedItems;
    }
}
```

At the bottom I have the method returning the list. How should I access this in another class?

Comment: You are missing this line of code --public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

Comment: Do you want to pass it through intent or without using it?

Comment: The list contains the checked items from my check box and I just want to get the selected items as a list so I can handle them.

Comment: first remove line selectedItems = new ArrayList<>(); from getview and then try

Comment: Removing this didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you create a new `ArrayList` everytime `getView()` is called, which is called a lot. And when you call the method `getListItems()` the method `getView()` is called before due to scrolling the listview or something. Remove the line

```
selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

from `getView()` method.

Another option is to make a class with static variables to hold the value during the applications lifetime

```
public class GlobalVars {
    public static List<String> selectedItems;
}
```

Comment: I think creating the global variables worked. Thanks so much!